# jquery getting values inside a ul li tag, but don't want a certain tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, text

I'm trying to get text value inside an `li` tag, but it has another tag that I don't want

example:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="close">x</a>text</li>
<li><a class="close">x</a>more text</li>
<li><a class="close">x</a>wohoooo more text</li>
</ul>
```

I can get tag like so

```
$("ul li").text();
```

but it also captures x from `a`. How do I remove the a tag? There's gotta be a simple solution that I'm not familiar with,

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("ul li").contents(':not(.close)').text()
```

children() does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment nodes, use .contents() http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 2):

#### Custom Pseudo-Class Filter

Write your own expression for grabbing textnodes:

```
$.extend( $.expr[":"], {
    textnodes: function( e ) {
        return e.nodeType === 3;
    }
});

$("ul li").contents(":textnodes");
```

Resulting in the following collection:

```
["text","more text","wohoooo more text"]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/T3MQc/

#### Custom Method

You could also extend `jQuery.fn` to provide your own method:

```
$.extend( $.fn, {
    textnodes: function() {
        return $(this).contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        });
    }
});

$("ul li").textnodes();
```

This results in the same output we see above.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/T3MQc/1/

Comment: Interesting concept, Thank you. I'll keep this noted.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty ugly, but it works. It clones the node, then removes all children and finally prints the text that's left:

```
$('ul li').clone()
  .children()
    .remove()
    .end()
  .text()
```

Managed to pull a nicer version from information fond here: [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

```
$('ul li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li')
   .contents()   // target to contents of li
   .filter(function() {    
      return this.nodeType == 3;  // filtering over textnode
}).text();  // get the text value
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/182/)**